# Disjoint cycle decomposition in $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to prove the following result:

> Show that if the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma\in A_n$ includes a cycle of even lenght or two cycles of the same odd lenght then $C_{S_n}(\sigma)\not \subset A_n$

Thanks

Comment: What is $C$ here?

Comment: it is the centralizer

Comment: Did you tried to see what happens for small $n$? What is the simplest non-trivial case?

Comment: See $(1, 2) \in C_{S_4}((1, 2)(3, 4)) \setminus A_4$, for example.

Comment: @Orat, your comment can be extended to $(1,2)\in \mathcal{C}_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4))$ for $n\geq4.$

Comment: your exemple is correct but i don't see how to prove the general result, Can you please help me?

Comment: How about $(14)(25)(36)\in C_{S_n}((123)(456))$? Please show some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Isn’t it pretty inconsiderate to the person that took the time to provide an answer, to keep removing the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outline, with some parts for you to complete . . .

Supose first that  in the disjoint cycle representation of $\sigma$, there is a cycle $c$ of even length. Since $c$ is disjoint from the cycles of $\sigma$ other than $c$, and since $c$ commutes with itself, it follows that $c$ commutes with $\sigma$. Since $c$ is a cycle of even length, it follows that $c$ is an odd permutation, hence $c \notin A_n$.

Next, suppose that in the disjoint cycle representation of $\sigma$, there are two cycles $a,b$ of the same length, $m$ say.

Show that $ab=c^2$, where $c$ is a cycle of length $2m$ whose entries are comprised of the entries of $a$ and $b$.

Since $c$ is disjoint from the cycles of $\sigma$ other than $a,b$, and since $c$ commutes with $ab$, it follows that $c$ commutes with $\sigma$. Since $c$ is a cycle of even length, it follows that $c$ is an odd permutation, hence $c \notin A_n$.

To help with your questions from the comments about how to find $c$ . . .

Suppose $a,b$ are disjoint $m$-cycles given by
$$a = (x_1\;x_2\;...\;x_m)$$
$$b= (y_1\;y_2\;...\;y_m)$$
Then verify that the $2m$-cycle
$$c = (x_1\;\,y_1\;\,x_2\;\,y_2\;\,...\;\,x_m\;\,y_m)$$
is such that $c^2=ab$.

Comment: I don't see clearly how to  ''Show that $ab=c^2$, where $c$ is a cycle of length $2m$ whose entries are comprised of the entries of $a$ and $b$'' can you please help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Work it out explicitly for the case where
$$a=(1\;...\;m),\;\;b=(m+1\;...\;2m)$$
To find the pattern, use small values of $m$.

Comment: $ab=(1,...,m,..,2m)$?

Comment: No. But as I said, to find the pattern, work it out for small values of $m$.

Comment: Another way to see it is  to use
$$a = (1\;3\;...\;2m-1),\;\;b=(2\;4\;...\;2m)$$
in which case, you can use $c=(1\;...\;2m)$. Try squaring $c$ to see what happens.

Comment: how do you find the the cycle $c$?

Comment: I did say that you have to do some work. So now it's your turn. Pick a small value of $m$, and let $c$ be the cycle $(1\;2\;...\;2m)$ of length $2m$. Square it, and find the disjoint cycle representation of the result.

Comment: for the first example what should i find for $c$?

Comment: Using an actual value of $m$, and using the $2m$-cycle
$$c = (1\;2\;...\;2m)$$
have you tried computing $c^2$? If not, that's your task.

Comment: i find $c^2=c$ is that right

Comment: No, $c$ is not the identity, so $c^2 \ne c$. It seems that you need to review the concept of disjoint cycle representation.

Comment: that is why i am asking how you find $c$ in fact $ab$ $1\mapsto 3$

Comment: For $m=3$, try squaring the $6$-cycle $c=(1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6)$. What is the disjoint cycle representation of $c^2$?

Comment: I find $c^2=(135)$?

Comment: No. Try again.${}{}$

Comment: $c^2=(135)(2,4,6)$? but how to compute when starting with  $a=(135)$ and $b=(2,4,6)$?

Comment: Yes, $c^2 = (1\;3\;5)(2\;4\;6)$.

Comment: that is what i am dowing $b$ send 1 to 1 and $a$ send 1 to 3, then $b$ send 3 to 3 and a send 3 to 5........and i find $ab=(135)(246)$ that does not change! i can not find c???

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!