# Prove that if a permutation $f \in A_n$ contains an independent cycle of even length then $f$ commutes with an odd permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hello I understand $A_n$ to an extend however I don't know how to prove this results and even when I have tried to verify it in $A_4$ it did not seem to commute?

Another similar proof I have struggled with is below, I think the result of one may lead to the other however I am not sure:

$1)$Prove that if a permutation $f \in A_n$ contains two independent cycles of the same length then $f$ commutes with an odd permutation

$2)$Prove that if a permutation $f \in A_n$ contains independent cycles of pairwise distinct odd lengths then $f$ does not commutes with odd permutations.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is fully answered by the first paragraph of my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628029/disjoint-cycle-decomposition-in-a-n

Comment: 2) Is imprecise. Does this mean that ALL cycles have pairwise distinct odd length? Does this include the fixed points? If the fixed points are not included, it is trivial to construct a counterexample.

Comment: As I read  it, the OP is not asking (1) or (2), but rather, trying to use them to prove the title question. Also, the OP probably misquoted (2) from whatever the source was, but the intention for (2) is ALL cycles, _including_ a possible fixed point (but no more tnan one).